# Displaying mark up/malicious code strings as literal strings

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net

I have a page containing a table to which values can be added via a textbox in a modal popup and the values will appear in the table on the page.
It is being tested by adding the string ); to the textbox and it fails because this string will initiate a popup. So I need to allow this code to be added and appear innocuously in its original format on the page without initiating a popup etc.
I've tried HTMLDecode('user added string') but this just cleanses the string and returns );
Is there a way to do this?

This is the table so the string is just being plonked in a cell so maybe something like a Literal would help?
But it has to be done client side - there is no server involvement.
I don't know how the code is initiated as someone else messed with that but it makes a raptor run across the screen - ridiculous.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Target Day(s)</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>));</Script><Script Src="//donastystuff1/X.Js"/></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why does adding `");"` to a `textbox` initiate a popup? You need to provide an example of your issue and what happens to the value.

Comment: How about showing us some code. How does adding `);` cause the popup to appear?

Comment: *HTMLDecode('user added string')* you have to encode it, not decode. [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input but I fixed it by adding the string to a Literal manually like this

```
var thisEventType = 'malicious string';
var $thisEventTypeCell = $('<td><asp:Literal id="litEventType" runat="server">' + '</asp:Literal></td>');
$thisEventTypeCell.text(thisEventType);
tr.append($thisEventTypeCell);
```

Comment: How did you add it before? Could have just used [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) in that case.

Comment: @Lain before the text was added to a <td></td> so completely open, now it's added to <td><asp:Literal></asp:Literal></td> which seems to render anything harmless. I'm not familar with textContent. Does it require a plug-in and do you have examples? Thanks

Comment: You have a link on it providing all information.